# Using 3d models in cocos2d project - is it possible?

Tags: iphone, 3d, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a cocos2d user and I wondered if there is any way I can combine 3d model animation in my project?

Comment: If your model use is constrained to an axis, you could render the 3d models as individual frames and add them in as 2d sprites.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should probably use [cocos3d](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/)

but you could also trying adding a [isgl3d](http://isgl3d.com/resources/community) view on top of the cocos2d scene

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there anyway I can keep using cocos2d and add individual 3d objects instead of transferring my existing project to cocos3d ?

Comment: I've not done it but I would guess that's what you should do as the site states: "Seamless integration with cocos2d. Rendering of all 3D model objects occurs within a special cocos2d layer, which fits seamlessly into the cocos2d node hierarchy, allowing 2D nodes such as controls, labels, and health bars to be drawn under, over, or beside 3D model objects. With this design, 2D objects, 3D objects, and sound can interact with each other to create a rich, synchronized audio-visual experience."

Comment: yes you can. Ive done it in my project. You need to include all the cocos3d files in your project then simply call cocos3d header and add a 3dWorld as a seperate layer to your scene.