# Add 3D Blender models to cocos2d iPhone game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, blender, cocos3d

I'm currently working on a 2 dimensional iPhone game using coco2d. I want to use a few 3D blender models in my game without rewriting the whole project from scratch in cocos3d.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/743) you can find what you are searching.
Also, here in stackoverflow this question have already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969099/using-3d-models-in-cocos2d-project-is-it-possible)